# Volume integral of a cone

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

I do have a little problem that just drives me crazy. It is about calculating the volume of a truncated cone. I have two solutions for it.

The object is limited by three areas: $A_1: z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2$, $A_2: z=-1$ and $A_3: z=1$. I tried to solve it with the formula for a volume found on wikipedia ([Link])[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum) with $h=2$, $r_1=1$ and $r_2=3$. The result was $\frac{26}{3}\pi$.

I want to calculate this with a volume integral and it delivers in cylindrical coordinates
$$V = \int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=1}^{3} \int_{z=-1}^{r-2} r \mathrm{d}z \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\varphi = \frac{28}{3}\pi$$

Can anybody see my fault? I didn't find similar questions for this, other cones were always centered in the origin. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This integral is the hollowed out truncated cone.  The cylinder from $r = 0$ to $r=1$ is missing.

Comment: This is what I actually thought, but why is the volume larger? It must become smaller, $\frac{26}{3}\pi$ ist the result.

Comment: The outer integral is correct, then you need to consider a variation for z from -1 to +1 and then for r from 0 to z+2

Comment: $z = -1$ to $r-2$ is the volume outside the section cone, inside the cylinder of radius 3 and height 2.  The cone points vertex down.

Comment: @Christoph If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

$$V = \int_{0}^{2\pi} {d}\varphi\int_{-1}^{1} \mathrm{d}z \int_{0}^{z+2} r  \mathrm{d}r \mathrm = \frac{26}{3}\pi$$

Comment: This solved my problem. My problem was that I had a limit $z(r)$ but ist must be $r(z)$ because $r$ is determined by the height and it begins with $z=-1$ and starts in $r=0$ because of the inner cylinder. Thanks.

Comment: @Christoph Since $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \implies z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2=r-2\implies r=z+2$

Answer (score 0):

Note that  $$\int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=1}^{3} \int_{z=-1}^{r-2} r \mathrm{d}z \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\varphi = \frac{20\pi}{3}$$  When you add the volume of the middle cylinder to this result you get the correct answer of $26\pi /3$

Comment: Very good, this is interesting for my first solution when I had the hollowed cone. So I geht $\int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^{1} \int_{z=-1}^{1} r \mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\varphi = 2\pi$ to add to the $\frac{20\pi}{3}$. Very interesting, that a change of the order of integration causes another volume, but also logic because of continuity of limits in this case.

Comment: Great comment.  As you know the problem could be solved with a single integral considering the solid as the solid of revolution but you wanted to take the more challenging path.